# Unicode vs ASCII memory

Tags: unicode

What is the difference between Unicode and ASCII in terms of memory? How much memory does Unicode and ASCII take in memory? I know that in Unicode it depends on the encoding type (UTF-8, UTF-16 etc..). But I need deeper understanding!

Comment: Have you googled for details? There are tons of documents that can give deeper understanding.

Comment: @EmacsUser yes I have but i get confused from so many materials and which exactly should I read... I need a summary exactly describing my problem :)

Comment: I understand, that's how we get lots of duplicate questions.

Comment: Why do you ask about ASCII? Outside of [RFCs](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc822#section-3.1) and MCUs, it's barely been used in decades. ISO 8859-1, Windows-1252 and CP437 and the like are far more common and even they are yielding to UTF-8.

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Answer (score 2):

In short, ASCII uses 7 bit code points (ie 7 bits uniquely identifies every character) where as Unicode is defined using 21 bit code points (0<sub>hex</sub> to 10FFFF<sub>hex</sub>, defined as 17 planes of 65536 / 16 bits of characters yields 1,114,112 characters - the nearest power of two is 2<sup>21</sup>). How much memory that uses depends on the way it is encoded in memory (not necessarily the same as the serialisation encoding used to externalise that data in files, typically one of UTF encodings for Unicode).

In practice ASCII is stored as one character per byte in RAM, and it is very rare to see pure ASCII, particularly outside of the USA - it is more common to see ISO8859-1 (an 8 bit encoding that is completely compatible with ASCII, but with other characters that use the extra bit that is available, eg for the £ and ¡ characters needed in some European countries).

Unicode is more complex, and representations vary considerably:

- Java uses 16 bit characters with the idea of a 'surrogate pair' to represent values that are outside the 'basic multilingual plane' (essentially any character added after Unicode 2.0). This is historic; early versions of Unicode used only 16 bits per character.
- In C it may often make sense to use the variable-length UTF-8 encoding as the in-memory representation - char is a byte after all, but with such encoding comes a small performance hit when decoding (it makes trying to find the n-th code point more difficult as one has to effectively iterate through the encoded byte array identifying the start of each character).
- It may also make sense to use UTF-32 (formerly known as UCS-4) as this encodes all Unicode codepoints in a 32 bit integer in a similar way to ASCII being stored in an 8 bit integer.

[Joel's article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) is golden reading for this topic.

Comment: i read that but got even more confused... So in a few words ASCII uses 7 bits and unicode 32??... Why have i heard that unicode uses 16 bits?

Comment: Because originally Unicode codepoints were 16 bits - in Unicode 3.0 this changed and 32 bits were used. A lot of documentation, and particularly the early Java oriented articles, was written before then. There are also a lot of people that genuinely believe this to be the case still - possibly because Java still uses char (a 16 bit primitive) as characters in strings (in the name of backward compatibility).

Comment: and what do bytes have to do with ASCII and Unicode... totally confused...

Comment: ASCII is a mapping of characters (and control codes) to numeric values that range from 0-127 (ie 2^7 - 1). Bytes are 8 bits wide, and commonly used for storage because they were originally a word width in early CPUs (and a fraction of a word on later CPUs). You have to store the data some how, and every data value has a representation in RAM - bytes are the most convenient units to work in as everything is measured using it.

Comment: ok got clear to some point... So basically ASCII is always 7 bits, but unicode can vary depending on the encoding? also always mess up the words encoding and... well is the UNICODE the encoding, or is it the UTF-X the encoding? (I know that UTF-X is a way of encoding using numbers) But I mess up the terms...

Comment: Almost - any ASCII character can be stored in 7 bits, but we usually store it in a byte (8 bits) for convenience and performance. Any Unicode character  can (currently) be stored in 32 bits, but to save storage space this may be represented in a different form, such as UTF-8 (Unicode Transformation Format - 8 bits). Most of the UTF-x formats are variable length encodings, which means a given code point will take a variable number of words to represent - in the case of UTF-8 this is 1-5 byte values, with the convenient property that the ASCII characters are represented with no transformation.

Comment: @john. Think of it this way: A character set has one or more encodings. For character sets with one overwhelmingly predominant encoding, that encoding is named the same as the character set. (Unicode _was_ like that with UCS-2 but then it grew up and we now have UTF-16 replacing UCS-2 and the unfortunate habit of Microsoft to call UTF-16 "Unicode".)

Comment: @john Not to give you a puzzle, but Unicode _codepoints_ are all 21 bits.

Comment: Thanks Tom - I have updated the answer slightly to note the 17 planes and that 21 bits is the smallest word size that can represent that range of characters.